# Better ternary condition

Tags: ruby

Method `find_something` may return `nil`. In the following code,

```
something = find_something(id) ? find_something(id) : create_something(foo)
```

`find_something(id)` is called twice. This is a smell that I want to avoid. Is there a way to avoid redundancy in this expression?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Anything like this?

```
something = find_something(id) || create_something(foo)
```

Comment: this is will only work if "find_something" return false. Here it return nil

Comment: It's the same. nil is a falsey value.

Comment: It will work as long as `find_something` can't legitimately return `false` as a found item.

Comment: Sure, but that does not work even with the original code, the ternary operator.

Comment: Sure. I just thought it warranted a heads-up for OP.

Answer (score 6):

There's not quite enough detail given to say this with confidence, though it might be this is a case for [`find_or_create_by`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-find_or_create_by).

If this does suit, you would just do:

```
something = YourModel.find_or_create_by(id: id)
```

You can also provide a block to this, which is passed to the create method if no record is found. For example:

```
something = YourModel.find_or_create_by(id: id) do |instance|
  # this block only gets executed on create
  instance.some_new_attribute = 'goes here'
end
```

Hope that's useful - let me know if it suits your use case.

Comment: Although this is a fine answer I suggest linking to https://api.rubyonrails.org/ since it is maintained by the official Ruby on Rails team. In this case [`find_or_create_by`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-find_or_create_by). For specific Rails versions use https://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.7/ replacing the version with the version you want to use.

Comment: Good advice, thanks @JohanWentholt. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Did you take a look at this @Xero? Wondering whether it was useful in your scenario?